# Why does cloudera recommend choosing the number of executors, cores, and RAM they do in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, bigdata

In the blog post:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

I was going about it in the naive way:

given 16 cores, 64 RAM, 8 threads - use 15 cores, 63 RAM, 6 executors.

Instead they recommend 17 executors, 5 cores, and 19 RAM. I see that they have an equation for RAM but I have no idea what’s going on.

Also does this still hold true if you are running it only on one machine(not through HDFS)?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they did a great job of explaining why [here](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/top-5-mistakes-to-avoid-when-writing-apache-spark-applications):
(Look at the slides starting at slide 5). 
For example, they don't recommend more than 5 cores per executor because lots of cores can lead to poor HDFS I/O throughput.

They recommend deciding on RAM as follows: once you have the number of executors per node (in the article, it is 3), you take the total memory and divide by executors/node. So, you have 63 GB RAM / 3 executors per node = 21 GB (take a bit away and get 19 GB - not clear why they do this.).

You certainly have the right idea when it comes to leaving some resources for the application master / overhead!

These options are optimized for cluster computing. But this makes sense since Spark is a cluster computing engine.

Comment: These are great slides thank you. Do you think that this would hold true for local computation without HDFS? Or does HDFS I/O have it's own set of problems/optimizations?

Comment: If you are using local computation on datasets small enough to fit on a single machine, why are you using Spark at all?

Comment: In addition to distributed tasks, I use it for efficient use of the cores present in my local machine. Joblib, although great, is much less powerful for distributing jobs and using RAM in an effective manner. I have found that it works really great for my purposes.

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately I've never used Spark on a single node, so I'm not sure if these rules apply equally as well to a single computer.